# I can't delete marks in IdeaVim, the VIM PyCharm plugin

Tags: vim, pycharm

Docs link: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#:delmarks.
(I usually use offical VIM ressources since I can use pretty much every shortcut with the plugin.)

When I try to type ":delmarks markLetter" and hit enter, I get an Windows error sound that usually hints me that a key that's invalid and the marks aren't deleted.
I also heard that there's a config file for VIM, but i don't know how I can access it with the plugin.
Also, this is my first post lol

Comment: Have You found a way to delete all marks at once ?